# Cant get the width() of Created Element -Jquery

Tags: jquery, width, slideshow

i have a little slide show created , i have a big wide screen to show the images full size and a small bar beneath of it for thumb images,
it will create the images ,create the container,and it will do it by a button...
every thing is fine ,the thumbs will be created in the container,

now i want to know which one of the images user hovers,and calculate the space between edge of container and the click images, for this i need each one of thumb width,(i comment the problem on the codes-the Second part)

and i want to get them by its id where user mouse hovers and do some extra movements, here is the problem,it just returns "undentified", i cant get the width of them,

"t" ,"w" and "s" are undentified in console log..

i can get them in case if i dont create the thumbs dynamiclly,

anyone Can help?

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/kUBsa/5/)

/////////////////first Part

```
var slides=new Array('_images/0.jpg' , '_images/1.jpg' , '_images/2.jpg' ,               '_images/3.jpg',
                         '_images/4.jpg','_images/5.jpg','_images/6.jpg',
                         '_images/7.jpg','_images/8.jpg');




var img = new Array();                       

$(function () {


    $('#start').click(function(){


        var thumbContainerWidth = 0 ;

        for( i = 0 ; i < slides.length ; i++){





            img[i] = $('<img class="thumb" id="thumb_' + i + ' " >');
            img[i].css({ "margin-left": 10 + "px"       ,
                         "opacity"    : 0               ,
                         "float"      : "left"          , 
                         "padding"    : "5px 0 5px 0"   ,

            });
            img[i].attr( "src",slides[i] );
            $('#thumbContainer').append( img[i] );

            //10px Extra space for paddings 
            temp = img[i].width() + 10 ;
            thumbContainerWidth += temp;
            $('#thumbContainer').width( thumbContainerWidth);
            console.log('Preperation ' + i);
            console.log(thumbContainerWidth );

       }



    //Start !

    var j = 0;

    handle = setInterval( function() {


            img[j].fadeTo(1500,1);

            console.log('here we go ->' + j);
            j++;

            if( j >= slides.length) {

                clearInterval( handle );
                return 1;
            }

    },1000);
```

////////////////////////Problem -Second Part

```
    $('.thumb').on("hover", function(){


        id  = $(this).attr('id');
        id = "#" + id;

        w = $(id).width();
        t = $('#thumb_5').width();

        var s = $(id).prevAll().width();
        $(id).css("opacity",".7");

        console.log(id +  '?' + w + '->' + s + t);

        } );    



    });





    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
temp = $('#thumb_'+i).width();
temp += 10;
```

or can directly like

```
temp = $('#thumb_'+i).width() + 10 ;
```

Comment: temp works fine, the last part doesnt work...w,t and s
$('.thumb').on("hover", function(){...

Answer (score 0):

give width to image tag, like

```
img[i] = $('<img class="thumb" id="thumb_' + i + ' " >');
```

replace with

```
img[i] = $('<img class="thumb" width="<your image width>" id="thumb_' + i + ' " >');
```

then you can get width of image from jQuery statement

I have fixed your jsFiddle and update, you can check it at http://jsfiddle.net/kUBsa/6/

Comment: i cant have my images in fiddle...or is there a way to add them ?

Comment: @OmidHosseini, you can't link your local image to jsFiddle.
so first you have to upload that image to your server or you can also use free image uploading service like http://postimage.org/ 

then use link that for image

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you are trying to get the width of the image right after you have appended its IMG tag to the DOM, when it's not loaded from the server yet.

You should make sure that you only start your calculation after your images have finished loading.

Comment: yep, i believe so ...the funny part is here ,first i have the image width immediately after creation....but when i want to get them by its id it doesnt work...

i tried so many differnt thing , .load . window and...
still the same...